# How to check if value is not changing in Python?

Tags: python, variables, count, raspberry-pi

How do I check if a Value is not changing? My Pi2GO Lite is counting how many steps it does while driving. Sometimes the wheels get stuck in something and wont move anymore. Sadly it doesn't notice that due to the lack of sensors. It has a lot of blind spots.

Thats the counting part of my code:

```
countL = 0
countR = 0
runL = True
runR = True
running = True
speed = 60


try:

  lastValidL = 2
  lastValidR = 2
  lastL = pi2go.irLeftLine()
  lastR = pi2go.irRightLine()
  while True:
    if pi2go.getDistance() >=8:
      while pi2go.getDistance() >=8:
        if countR > countL:
          pi2go.turnForward(90,85)
        if countR < countL:
          pi2go.turnForward(85,90)
        if countR == countL:
          pi2go.turnForward(85,90)
        val = pi2go.irLeftLine()
        if val == lastL and val != lastValidL:
          countL +=1
          lastValidL = val
        lastL = val
        print "L:", countL
        val = pi2go.irRightLine()
        if val == lastR and val != lastValidR:
          countR += 1
          lastValidR = val
        lastR = val
        print "R:", countR
#heres the function I want.
        oldL = countL +
        print oldL
        if True:
          if oldL == countL:
            time.sleep(5) 
            #if oldL has still the same value as count L
            if oldL == countL 
              pi2go.stepReverse(80,20)
```

now my problem is:
 while "time.sleep(5)"
 the counter stops too. so countL and oldL are definitely the same as before.

- oldL is refreshing all the time so its ALWAYS the same value as countL

how do i create a variable with the value of the current Count without the variable changing with every count? I need a "static" number if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

In python, Static functionality can be achieved by a global variable.

your question is not clear enough to understand.